# How to make this menu

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

How to create this menu inside the layout itself and not inside a sliding navigation menu like this:

[image: Menu Example]

Using the menu-item like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="Vehicle Info"
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_vehicle_info"/>

    <item
        android:title="Car Parts"
        android:id="@+id/car_parts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_car_parts"/>

    <item
        android:title="Photos"
        android:id="@+id/photos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_photos"/>

    <item
        android:title="Review"
        android:id="@+id/review"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_review"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "inside the layout itself"? Do you want it in the ActionBar like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*OZxvGuCUiHsLnu55JOQhyQ.png) ?

Comment: no, not in the actionbar, i want it displayed like the one in the image, where the menu (Loan record, Online Service, etc...) is not inside an actionbar and is displayed on the main layout

Comment: Hope this will be of some help https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create a layout file. Just like I created nav_item_update.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    >


   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_mood"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="jawad"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_more"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

After that you have to add an actionLayout attribute in your menuItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                tools:showIn="navigation_view">

                <item android:id="@+id/nav_item1"
                      app:showAsAction="always"
                      android:title="@null"
                      app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_item_updated" />

                <item android:id="@+id/nav_item2"
                      app:showAsAction="always"
                      android:title="@null"
                      app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_item_updated" />
       </menu>
```

and that's it.

[image: Custom menu items]